# ubuntu 22 does not resolve hostnames without domainname

Tags: networking, server, dns, display-resolution

We've got a bunch of ub20 VM's

where the resolv.conf looks like

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search domain.nl
```

both ping to machine tooling and tooling.domain.nl works, ip address resolved

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

on these machines a ping to machine tooling.domain.nl works but without domain name it says "Temporary failure in name resolution"

manually changing resolv.conf to search domain.nl does not work, the dot is replaced automatically

How to setup name resolution without domain name?

Comment: Having same issue, found any solution?

Comment: it seems to have something to do with /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml which is automatically overwitten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating the netplan yaml in "/etc/netplan" with search: domain.nl

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.203.32.254
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.203.32.131/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 10.203.32.2
          - 10.203.32.3
        search:
        - domain.nl
```

Now after netplan apply, resolv.conf contains the line "search domain.nl" and it works